# Gostaria de saber se sabeM como Fazer com que a barra fique sobre outra barra no Gráfico timeline API Google

Tags: google-charts

Trata-se de um gráfico de escala, quero fazer com que as pausas, fiquem em cima da barra da escala.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"],'language':"pt_BR"});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {

            var container = document.getElementById('Grafico_Jornada');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Data' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Status' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Inicio' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Fim' });
            dataTable.addRows([
              //[ '\0', '\0',       new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0) ],
              [ '18/12/2016', 'Jornada',       new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '18', 'Problemas Técnicos',    new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '19/12/2016', 'Jornada',        new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '19',   'Logado',    new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '20/12/2016', 'Jornada',        new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '20',   'Logado',    new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '21/12/2016', 'Jornada',       new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '21/12/2016', 'Pausa 10',    new Date(0,0,0,1,45,0),  new Date(0,0,0,1,55,0) ],
              [ '21/12/2016', 'Intervalo',    new Date(0,0,0,2,45,0),  new Date(0,0,0,3,0,5) ],
              [ '21', 'Problemas Técnicos',    new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,0,30,0) ],
              [ '21', 'Logado',    new Date(0,0,0,0,30,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '22/12/2016', 'Jornada',        new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '22',   'Logado',    new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
              [ '23/12/2016',   'Jornada', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '23',   'Atestado',     new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '24/12/2016', 'Jornada',       new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '24',   'Problemas Técnicos',     new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,3,20,0) ],
              [ '25/12/2016',   'Jornada', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ],
              [ '25',   'Folga',    new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,6,20,0) ]]);

            var options = {
              //Jornada FF3333, PT ECA013, logado 1CA261,pausa 10 6699FF, intervalo 6633FF,atestado, folga dsr 0ECFE4
              colors: ['#FF3333','#ECA013','#1CA261','#6699FF','#6633FF','#9933CC','#0ECFE4'],
              timeline: { 
                colorByRowLabel: false,                
                barLabelStyle: { fontSize: '10'}
            },
              hAxis: {
                minValue: new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),
                maxValue: new Date(0,0,0,24,0,0),
                format: "k:mm"}

              };          


            chart.draw(dataTable, options);

          }

        </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
      <div align="center">          
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Painel de Visualização da Escala</h3>
        <div id="Grafico_Jornada" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px;" ></div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

outra coisa que gostaria é de Fazer aparecer todas as hora e não de 2 em 2, usei o gridlines.count do hAxis, mas não tive exito